Fisher's alpha diversity index
Fisher's alpha diversity index is defined by the formula $S=a ln(1+\frac{n}{a})$. How do I calculate the value of $a$ for known values of $S$ and $n$? For example when $S=5$ and $n=184$ the value of $a\approx0.948174$ but I cannot figure out the steps.

Welcome to Math SE! To write mathematical expressions, please use MathJax formatting. More info can be found here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

@LSK21 Thank you. I edited the post above accordingly.
